# lazy.nvim: Upgrade plugins from command line

Tags: neovim, packages

I have a script that updates my system. It updates system packages, remove orphaned packages, update R packages,  update software pip-installed in python virtual environments.

I would like to use this Bash script to update my Neovim plugins as well.

I use lazy.nvim as package manager.

Is is possible to update the plugins from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs at https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim:

`$ nvim --headless "+Lazy! sync" +qa`

Comment: Ops ... I should have read that!

Comment: @robertspierre You aren't by chance trying to get this to work in a Dockerfile are you? I can't seem to get it to work from a dockerfile but it works fine if I run it from a running container. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: no just normal command line

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
nvim -c "Lazy update" -c "sleep 120" -c "qa"
```

Or using `cmd` Windows argument passing:

```
nvim -c "Lazy update"  -c "sleep 120"  -c "call feedkeys("":qa\<cr>"")"
```

Or using `bash` Linux arguments passing:

```
nvim -c "Lazy update"  -c "sleep 120"  -c "call feedkeys(\":qa\\<cr>\")"
```

For most of the plugins the only thing that Lazy is doing is doing a `git pull` on each plugin folders (`~/.config/nvim-data/lazy/*`)

`update_plugins.sh`

```bash
pushd ~/.config/nvim-data/lazy
for file in *; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        continue
    fi
    echo "Update: " $file
    cd $file
    git pull
    cd ..
done
popd
```

Comment: Uhm I tried the first one and it didn't seem to work. There were several updates that were not retrieved.

Comment: I have Linux BTW

Comment: If you don't add the code that close Neovim (`-c "q") do you get all the updates?

Comment: why the feedkeys() function instead of just using `-c"q"`?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt my tests were failing but probably because I was using `q` instead of `qa`. I have adapted the answer.  The `feedkeys` makes that Vim process it only when it is ready to consume tokens. What remains to clarify is: are the plugin post installation procedure complete when the `Lazy update` command ends?

Comment: yeah, perhaps it's running in async mode and so the `:q` is processed before the update is complete

Comment: The third command `nvim -c "Lazy update" -c "call feedkeys(\":qa!\\<cr>\")"` gives me `bash: history: nvim -c "Lazy update" -c "call feedkeys(\":qa!\\<cr>\")": history expansion failed`

Comment: This because you have history extension in your shell and it probably try to convert `!"` into something else. You can test by removing the exclamation mark. But I fear the call to `Lazy update` is asynchronous and a delay need to be introduced. Or another technique used.

Comment: But there is no `!"` in that command. The first command doesn't work, nvim closes immediately.

Comment: You can remove the `!` from the command (right after the `qa`) but I fear it will not be enough. A delay need to be added before the `feedkeys`. I believe my other suggestion using `git` is better :-/

Comment: I have  provided a new version that wait for 2 minutes for the Update to occur or that use the `git pull` technique in bash :-)